# getImageData returns values from previous uploaded picture not current

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong when the code below returns values from the previous uploaded picture not the current one?

```
    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     


    var imageWidth = canvas.width;
    var imageHeight = canvas.height;


    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
    var data = imageData.data;

    console.log("imageWidth=" +imageWidth);
```

The image is uploaded through the input below:

```
  <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
  <br>
  <input type='file' id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
  <br>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `reader.onload` is called asynchronously, as is `img.onload` - oops, didn't see the answer

Comment: also, your code is indented randomly

Comment: Thanks, you were spot on also. Yes, the indentation is quite awful, I need to fix that issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` event of `FileReader` and `<img>` are both asynchronous. Place

```
var imageWidth = canvas.width;
var imageHeight = canvas.height;

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
var data = imageData.data;

console.log("imageWidth=" +imageWidth);
```

within `<img>` `load` event handler.

You can also set `.value` of `<input type="file">` element to `""` to remove reference to current uploaded `File` object from the elements' `.files` property.